# Cakephp One login function / multiple login views

Tags: cakephp, authentication, view

I have one website with a login system. However, I would like the login view to be different depending on what link has the user used to get to the login screen.

Something like:

```
function login ($from_page = null) {

    if (isset($page)) $this->render('login_alternate_view');
    else $this->render('login'); //default login view
}
```

And then each of the login views (login.ctp, login_alternate_view.ctp) would have the login form plus other stuff specific to each one.

Is this possible in some way? I've already tried something like the example above but it doesn't work...

Comment: Should `isset($page)` be something like `!empty($from_page)`?

Comment: Maybe, but my main problem is that when I pass a parameter to the login function (like /users/login/variable) I get an error

Comment: well, the thing is that I use ajax to call that function and show it in a popover. If I call /users/login, no problem at all. If I call /users/login/something then it says _Request failed: error_ or something like that

Comment: I can do everything in just one view (login.ctp), but I still need a way of knowing somehow what link the user has used...

Comment: That should work like that. We would need to see more code. Maybe you have a route which is causing the problem.

Comment: I don't know, I don't think I have set up any route. It's weird the the error show only when I add a parameter to the login function. Anyways, I just fixed it using GET variables in the url

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed it using GET variables:

```
/users/login?some_var=some_value
```

And then in the login function I catch that variable's value with:

```
$this->params['url']['some_var'];
```

This way I can "customize" my login function depending on the link the user uses

Answer (score 0):

First show the real error message you're talking in the comments about and not "something".

I guess that you want the current page url the user is on when he logs in? How to you generate the modal? Request the whole form via ajax or is it embedded in the page you're on? If it's embedded I would put the current page url the user is on in a hidden field "from" in the login form and check that.

Comment: I can't use the current page because from one same page the user has more than one login option, so I need to know the exactly link he used. I figured this out, I posted the answer